# Map primary key to non-primary key in another table with different name

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have an object I'll call Foo, I want to map Foo like so:

```
Foo
-FooId (PK)
-Country
-Name
-Amount
```

The problem is the database design is poor, so I have two tables with no link table:

```
Foo (TABLE)
-FooId (PK)
-CountryId (problem child here) - COUNTRY_ID
-Name
-Amount

FooCountry (TABLE)
-CountryId (PK)
-CountryName
-ActualCountryId (I want to tie this to the "Foo" CountryId) - ACTUAL_ID
```

I'm using an older version of hibernate and Java, so I don't have access to annotations, it all has to be done with plain old XML mapping.

In short, I want to map column "CountryId" to column "ActualCountryId" AND get the full values inside the FooCountry table based on it (i.e. "Country" as in first example). I am quite sure the "ActualCountryId" column is unique, but it isn't coded that way in the DB, it's just a normal property column.

Can anyone figure this trick out?

Edit: As an added bonus, how would I define the "Country" object within Foo? As a FooCountry?

Edit: This is my mapping inside the Foo XML class area

```
<key-many-to-one  name="countryId" class="FooCountry" property-ref="actualCountryId" column="COUNTRY_ID" />
```

I also added the column names for both tables.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a many-to-one association, but with a foreign key to a column which is not the primary key of the target table. This is well described in the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7761). You just have to use `property-ref="propertyNameFromAssociatedClass"` in the `many-to-one` element.

The `FooCountry` table must be mapped as a regular entity.

Comment: FooCountry is mapped as a regular entity, I'll try this out.

Comment: I get a "Attribute 'property-ref' used but not declared." error, is mapping in the class file incorrect? Or the mapping overall?

Comment: You are correct in what I need, btw. The specific tag I'm using is key-many-to-one in Hib v3.0

Comment: I don't know. edit your question with the mapping, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Ok, added further info above, also on tables and column names

Comment: Why using a ker parimaryy-many-to-one? The country ID is not part of the ID of Foo. You should just have a many-to-one. And the Foo should have a property country of type FooCountry.